Count all odd paths in a tree
My task is, given an acyclic non-direct graph, to count the pairs of nodes connected by an odd number of edges.
My question is why should I start searching the graph from those vertices which have odd degree? Or, doesn't it matter?

Re: "why should I start searching the graph from those vertices which have odd degree?": Can you explain what has led you to think that?

@ruakh mainly some guesses, someone recommended me to read about these degrees of vertices and somehow I came to it, but if I'm wrong then please help me out

An acyclic connected graph is a tree. If it's not connected, then it's a forest, which is a collection of trees.
I'll assume it's connected, but if not, apply this to each tree.

Pick any node.
Run BFS from the node, counting the number of nodes that are an even & odd distance from the starting node, and including the starting node in the count of nodes that are an even distance from it.
return (count of odd-distance nodes) * (count of even-distance nodes)


So, why does this work?
Let's say X is the node we pick in the first bullet, and Y & Z are any two other nodes. Since our graph is a tree, there is one path between X & Y, between X & Z, and between Y & Z.
Say the X-Y path is X, p1, p2, ..., pk, Y.
Say the X-Z path is X, q1, q2, ..., qt, Z.
It's possible that there's no overlap between these paths, but they may overlap. Let's say that the first r nodes overlap, so that pi == qi for 1 <= i <= r.
Then, the path between Y & Z is: pk, p(k-1), p(k-2), ..., pr == qr, q(r+1), q(r+2), ..., qt.
The parity of this is even IFF the parity of the path between qr & qt is the same as the parity of the path between pr & pt. But, since pr == qr, these parities are the same IFF the parity of the X-qt and X-pk are the same.

And there is some kind of theory for this assignement or this is algorithm based on "brain logic

@AleksanderJanic Which bit do you need help with? The first statement about trees and forests is a definition. "A tree is an acyclic connected graph" -- Graphs & Digraphs 2nd edition by Chartrand & Lesniak. I'll edit the answer shortly to explain the bullets in case that's what's unclear.

@AleksanderJanic I added an explanation. Hope that helps.

I wonder if this task of mine is some kind of a common one and there is a more comprehensive explanation for it, why we are proceeding in this way in search of this answer or this is task with only BFS implements

@AleksanderJanic I don't think it's common question, or at least I don't know of a common reason why people would care to know how many pairs of nodes in a tree are connected by an odd number of edges. What are you hoping to get out of a more comprehensive explanation?

What is an p,q and r?

I could picture this problem being connected to graph coloring problems. Color the graph red/blue, how many ways can you pick a red / blue pair, etc.  Anyways, excellent solution.

@AleksanderJanic p & q are nodes, and r is the subscript of the last node the X-Y and X-Z paths share.
